# How to add jquery.css file in Twig?

Tags: templating, css

I am working on a project and the plug in I installed won't work because I don't know how to add the jquery.css file needed.

What I did is to add the file with a `<link>` command but it's still not working.

Any help would be great.

```
    {% block body %}
<link type="text/css"  href="{{ asset('home/workspace/fermate/src/CtrlBln/HomepageBundle/Resources/public/js/Minimal-jQuery-Image-Viewer-with-Image-Preloading-ABigImage/bigimage.jquery.css')}}" > 
<div class="page-sidebar">
    {% for link in entity.getSidebarImages() %}
        {% if link.image.isFoto() %}            
            <a href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.getWebPath() }}">         
                <img src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.getWebPath("thumbnail_250") }}" alt="{{ link.image.title }}">                        
                <div class="sidebar-description">
                    {{ link.image.description|raw }}
                </div>  
            </a>        
        {% else %}
            <div class="sidebar-item sidebar-link-item">
                <a href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.webpath }}">

                 <img src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.getPreview() }}" />
                </a>
                <div class="sidebar-title">
                    <a href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.webpath }}">
                      {{ link.image.title|raw }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}    
<script>
$(function(){
    $(this).abigimage();
});   
</script>
</div>
{% endblock %}

    {% block body_javascripts %}
        {% javascripts output='aBigImage.js'
        '@CtrlBlnHomepageBundle/Resources/public/js/Minimal-jQuery-Image-Viewer-with-Image-Preloading-ABigImage/abigimage.jquery.min.js'    
        %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `asset()` a Twig [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) you've defined?

Are you sure you're just not looking for the global [`url()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/functions#url) method instead?